# How to hot encode data in a csv by using headers

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a large list of data of malware analysis , I have added all the unique features in a header like :

```
label,md5,create new key via CryptAcquireContext,delete user account group,send file via HTTP
```

I have data like in my csv like:

```
malware,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,packed with UPX,delete user account group
malware,1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3,inspect load icon resource,reference analysis tools strings,send file via HTTP
```

I want to perfrom one hot encoding where if the value after hash matches header than I will change it to 1 if not than It will be 0 , what is the best way of acheiving this.

```
import csv

def one_hot_encode(header, data):
    encoded_data = []
    for row in data:
        encoded_row = []

        # Iterate through each element in the row
        for element in row:
            # Check if the element matches the current header
            if element == header:
                encoded_row.append(1)  # Match found, set to 1
            else:
                encoded_row.append(0)  # No match, set to 0

        encoded_data.append(encoded_row)

    return encoded_data

def main():
    headers = []
    output_file = "feature-list.txt"

    # Read the headers from the text file
    with open(output_file, 'r') as txt_file:
        for line in txt_file:
            line = line.strip()  # Remove trailing newline characters
            headers.append(line)

    headers.insert(1, "md5")
    headers.insert(0, "label")
    input_file = 'cleaned_features-test-2.csv'
    output_file = 'cleaned_features-test2_updated.csv'

    # Read existing data from the CSV file
    existing_data = []
    with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            existing_data.append(row)

    # Perform one-hot encoding for each header
    encoded_data = []
    for header in headers:
        encoded_data.extend(one_hot_encode(header, existing_data))

    # Write the custom header and encoded data to a new CSV file
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        # Write the custom header
        writer.writerow(headers)

        # Write the encoded data
        writer.writerows(encoded_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [by showing your code](/help/how-to-ask), at the very least (in [mcve] form of course). Without any information on how you're doing what you claim to be doing, there's not much people can meaningfully comment on.

Comment: are the headers being sent in plain text?  If yes then simply tokenize based on commas and match individual values to the rows in CSV and assign 1 or 0. 

May be I am not seeing the problem here, and some more information in the question might help like @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans suggested

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans its a security risk but for you ill take the small risk , here is what i came up with so far

Comment: okay so what's the issue you are facing with that code? Seems like you are on the right track.

Comment: trying to not overwrite hash and label and verify if the 0,1's are valid